# Where are required gems defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

In my rails application I once used `authlogic-oid` and `ruby-openid`. Now I want to get rid of them and I removed both gems and also their `config.gem` lines from my `environment.rb`.

Although my application works, I can't do any database migrations because I get a "Missing these required gems" error.  Also if I run `rake gems:install` these gems are re-installed.

Where are the references to the gems stored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard way to define a gem dependency is in the environment configuration. It usually takes place in the environment.rb file for any environment, but some gems might be specified also per-environment. Check the environment files in `config/environments`.

Also make sure some file doesn't include the gem with the classic RubyGems `gem` command.

Finally, check these gems are not required by other gems or plugins used by your application.

Comment: Additionally I found out, that plugins can require their own gems, as it was the case in my situation. If you add that to your answer, I'll accept it :)